# Laravel 5 hasMany relationship on two columns

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

Is it possible to have a hasMany relationship on two columns?

My table has two columns, `user_id` and `related_user_id`.

I want my relation to match either of the columns.

In my model I have

```
public function userRelations()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\UserRelation');
}
```

Which runs the query: `select * from user_relations where user_relations.user_id in ('17', '18')`.

The query I need to run is:

```
select * from user_relations where user_relations.user_id = 17 OR user_relations.related_user_id = 17
```

**EDIT:**

I'm using eager loading and I think this will affect how it will have to work.

```
$cause = Cause::with('donations.user.userRelations')->where('active', '=', 1)->first();
```

Comment: Maybe it's better just filter the `UserRelation` model by this two columns?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

I don't think it's possible to do exactly what you are asking.

I think you should treat them as separate relationships and then create a new method on the model to retrieve a collection of both.

```
public function userRelations() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\UserRelation');
}

public function relatedUserRelations() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\UserRelation', 'related_user_id');
}

public function allUserRelations() {
    return $this->userRelations->merge($this->relatedUserRelations);
}
```

This way you still get the benefit of eager loading and relationship caching on the model.

```
$cause = Cause::with('donations.user.userRelations', 
        'donations.user.relatedUserRelations')
    ->where('active', 1)->first();

$userRelations = $cause->donations[0]->user->allUserRelations();
```

Comment: Why I get this? Call to undefined method Illuminate\\Database\\Query\\Builder::merge()

Comment: Remove the brackets after userRelations @ciccioassenza :)

Comment: Hmm you noticed I asked that question 3 years ago @developerbmw :)

Comment: Yes I did notice however I couldn't resist pointing that out :) @ciccioassenza

Comment: if the above 'merge' solution doesn't work for you then try a 'union' instead: return $this->userRelations()->union($this->relatedUserRelations()->toBase());

Answer (score 24):

[Compoships](https://github.com/topclaudy/compoships) adds support for multi-columns relationships in Laravel 5's Eloquent.

It allows you to specify relationships using the following syntax:

```
public function b()
{
    return $this->hasMany('B', ['key1', 'key2'], ['key1', 'key2']);
}
```

where both columns have to match.

Comment: Does Compoships support relations where all columns have to match or also what the topic owner asked for, i.e. that only one of two columns matches? It isn't really clear from its description.

Comment: @Namoshek The user asked "Is it possible to have a hasMany relationship on two columns?" - No. With default Laravel setup. Yes, by using Compoships. To answer your question, all columns have to match.

Comment: @topclaudy In this case your answer doesn't really provide a solution to his problem. The author wants his `relation to match either of the columns`, not both. It can still be helpful for other users though. Maybe you should just clearify in your answer that it has to match all columns to work.

Comment: @Namoshek Fixed!

Answer (score 5):

I'd prefer doing it this way:

```
public function userRelations()
{
    return UserRelation::where(function($q) {
        /**
         * @var Builder $q
         */
        $q->where('user_id',$this->id)
            ->orWhere('related_user_id',$this->id);
    });
}

public function getUserRelationsAttribute()
{
    return $this->userRelations()->get();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If anyone landed here like me due to google: 
As neither merge() (as suggested above) nor push() (as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36642874/11335307)) allow eager loading (and other nice relation features), the discussion is still ongoing and was continued in a more recent thread, see here: [Laravel Eloquent Inner Join on Self Referencing Table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55113114/laravel-eloquent-inner-join-on-self-referencing-table)

I proposed a solution [there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55752491/11335307), any further ideas and contributions welcome.

Comment: Please don't write link-only answers.

Answer (score 0):

You can handle that things with this smart and easy way .

```
$cause = Cause::with(['userRelations' => function($q) use($related_user_id) {
        $q->where('related_user_id', $related_user_id);
    }])->where('active', '=', 1)->first();
```