# How to relate all rows in a table to all other rows in the same table?

Tags: mysql, laravel-5

In Laravel can I create a relationship between 2 ids in the same table? In my case the hamming distance between 2 photos.
I want to save the hamming_distance of every id to every other id. One for each relationship. No Dups. Not worried about scale or how long it takes to generate each hamming_distance. Really just looking for the best schema to handle this.

Photos Table

```
id
path
etc
```

Another table. Or whatever is suggested as 2 columns of the same name obviously will not work

```
photo_id
photo_id
hamming_distance
```

Comment: would this be a possible [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29751859/laravel-5-hasmany-relationship-on-two-columns)

Comment: It is close. So a schema of photo_id and related_photo_id is a reasonable start. My query would need to be something like "Where photo_id = 17 and related_photo_id = 18 OR photo_id = 18 and related_photo_id = 17". I imagine there is a better way

Answer (score 0):

In Your 2nd Table

```
public function Photo(){

   return $this->belongsTo('App\Photo', 'photo_id', 'id');
}
```

For More Details https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one

Comment: Could you show me the schema of the second table that would make this work. This is not how I understand One to One. Every photo has a relationship to every other photo.