# Laravel is there a way to have relation belongsTo based on two columns?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have the following tables and want to get all units (base unit, and sub units) of the product

**Units**

| id | name | multiplier | base_unit_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Piece | 1 | null |
| 2 | Dozen - 12 | 12 | 1 |

**Products**

| id | name | cost | price | unit_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | product1 | 10 | 14 | 1 |
| 1 | product2 | 10 | 14 | 1 |

Relationship inside **Product Model**

```php
public function units()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Unit::class, 'unit_id', 'id'); // Or where base_unit_id = product unit id
    // I have tried this
    // $this->belongsTo(Unit::class, 'unit_id', 'id')->orWhere('base_unit_id', $this->unit_id)
    // Does not work
}
```

I like to get the products like so

```php
$products = Product::with('units')->get();
```

Expected output is

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Product 1",
        "unit_id": 1,
        "cost": 10,
        "price": 14,
        "units": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "Piece",
                "multiplier": 1,
                "base_unit_id": null
            },
            {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "Dozen - 12",
                "multiplier": 12,
                "base_unit_id": 1
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Product 2",
        "unit_id": 1,
        "cost": 10,
        "price": 14,
        "units": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "Piece",
                "multiplier": 1,
                "base_unit_id": null
            },
            {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "Dozen - 12",
                "multiplier": 12,
                "base_unit_id": 1
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I want the units in one list how can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the solution that I came up with after looking for a while.

**Product Model**

```php
public function baseUnit()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Unit::class, 'unit_id', 'id');
}
```

**Unit Model**

```php
public function subUnits()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Unit::class, 'base_unit_id', 'id');
}
```

And you can call it like

```php
$product = Product::with(['baseUnit.subUnits'])->get();
```

Which gets you this output

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Product 1",
        "unit_id": 1,
        "cost": 10,
        "price": 14,
        "base_unit": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Piece",
            "multiplier": 1,
            "base_unit_id": null,
            "sub_units": [
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "name": "Dozen - 12",
                    "multiplier": 12,
                    "base_unit_id": 1
                }
            ]
        }
    }
]
```

And you can make a helper function inside the **Product Model** to format the units  like this.

```php
public function units()
{
    $baseUnit = $this->baseUnit->replicate(); // Clone it so we don't modify the original
    $baseUnit->id = $this->baseUnit->id; // Set the id to the original unit id
    $result = collect();
    $baseUnit->subUnits->each(function ($unit) use (&$result) {
        $result->push($unit);
    });
    $baseUnit->offsetUnset('subUnits');
    $result->push($baseUnit);
    unset($baseUnit);
    return $result;
}
```

Output

```
[ 
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Dozen - 12",
        "multiplier": 12,
        "base_unit_id": 1
    },
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Piece",
        "multiplier": 1,
        "base_unit_id": null
    }
]
```

Thanks to everyone who took time to answer me.

Answer (score 0):

There's no easy way to do this.

My solution is using `getAttribute`:

```
public function getUnitsAttribute()
{
    Unit::where('id', $this->unit_id)->orWhere('base_unit_id')->get();
}
```

But anyway, you can't use relation methods (like `with()` or `load()`) and you can't use it like a query builder.

Also, you can try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29775608/19262677.

Comment: I didn't think of that. will try and see how it goes. Thank You

Answer (score 0):

You will need to implement **many-to-many** relation between **Product** and **Unit** models via a pivot table

Basically it's like: **Product** record can have many **Unit** records
and **Unit** record can have many **Product** records - **Many-to-Many**

```php
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('product_unit', function(Blueprint $table) {
        $table->foreignId('product_id')->constrained('products')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->foreignId('unit_id')->constrained('units')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->timestamps();

        $table->primary(['product_id', 'uint_id']);
    });
}

public function down()

{
    Schema::dropIfExists('product_unit');
}
```

Next you need to define relationships

```php
//Product model
public function units()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Unit::class)->withTimestamps();
}
```

```php
//Unit model
public function products()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class)->withTimestamps();
}
```

[Laravel Docs - Eloquent Relationships - Many-to-Many](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many)

[Laravel Docs - Eloquent Relationships - Updating Many-to-Many relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#updating-many-to-many-relationships)

Comment: @JihadHashm No worries. Looking at the table structures **many-to-many** relationship pops out as the most convenient way to go forward. However there are many different approaches one may take - it's ultimately a matter of choice. Good luck

Comment: Thank you. I'm sorry deleted my previous comment by mistake new to stack overflow :).
I will still look if no luck I will try to change the database structure like you said then.

Comment: @JihadHashm You don't need to change your existing tables `units` or `products` just add a new migration for the `product_unit` pivot table - and define **belongsToMany** relationships - that's it.

Comment: Yes I will do that if I don't find other solution. Thanks.