# How can I merge two hasMany relations from the same table?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.1

I want to merge two hasMany relations at one Model method. The two relations are nearly identical, the only difference is the foreign key.

Please note that I cannot simply call the query builders `get()` Method on both relations because I have to work with the merged relation, not the collection, e.g. I want to sort the merged relation later, or call `->where()` on it.

Here is a sample code:

**Friend.php**

```php
<?php
class Friend extends Model
{
  /*
  Database structure:
  - id
  - user_id
  - friend_id
  */

  public function user()
  {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\User');
  }
  public function friend()
  {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\User', 'friend_id');
  }
}
```

**User.php**

```php
<?php
class User extends Model
{
  /*
  Database structure:
  - id
  [...]
  */

  public function friends()
  {
    $friends_left = $this->hasMany('App\Models\Friend', 'friend_id');
    $friends_right = $this->hasMany('App\Models\Friend', 'user_id');
    // return single relation
  }
}
```

Comment: By definition, one Model/table has only one identifier, it looks like that Friend model would have two identifiers... is that even possible?

Comment: Maybe this is helpful : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24184069/laravel-merge-reltationships

Comment: @Amarnasan yes I found that question, too, but that did not solve my problem, because there it merges two collections to one single collection meaning that I can no longer call query methods on it.

Comment: But what kind of "query method" do you intend to perform? Can you give an example? Because I don't think you can perform a "get" after any "hasMany". I mean, you can't do this: $this->user()->get(), even if the "user()" is a standard "hasMany" relationship, because it will not return a "query" object, but a collection of object of a given model.

Comment: What I currently get is an object of the type `Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder` (e.g. the variable `$friends_left` is from that type)

Comment: @Amarnasan An example would be `$friends_merged->where('created_at', '>=', date())`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know it's awful but... consider transforming your merged collection to a new query like this:

```
    $collection1 = ...;
    $collection2 = ...;
    $collection = $collection1->merge($collection2);
    $values = $collection->lists('id');
    $query = User::whereIn('id',$values)->....and continue with your queries;
```

Comment: Well except that this solution causes another database query the performance loss won't be too high because of the primary key lookup. At least this is a low-effort workaround.