# Unable to merge two Eloquent collections

Tags: laravel, merge, model, eloquent

I have a table named `messages` in my database and, it has five columns as:

```
id | sender_id | receiver_id | message | sent_at
```

And, in my model `User`, I have a function that looks like this:

```
    public function messages(){

      $sent_messages = $this->hasMany(Message::class, "sender_id");

      $received_messages = $this->hasMany(Message::class, "receiver_id");

      $messages = $sent_messages->merge($received_messages);

      return $messages;

    }
```

I opined that it would work but it didn't. The error I get is:

```
BadMethodCallException with message 'Call to undefined method Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder::merge()'
```

So, what did I do wrong and what can I do to get all the `messages` if its either sent by me or received by me?

Comment: please refer, i hope this will helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24184069/laravel-merge-relationships

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to have a Collection you must use the `->get()` method. Otherwise you have the relation objects and you can't merge them ;)