# Conditional wherehas with Laravel Eloquent

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have one similar (`area`) value in two tables `one` and `two` and these two tables has relation with main table `master`. At a time, the `master` table will be having data in one relation only and the other one will be `null`.

With this architecture, I have a search page where user can search any values related to these tables and the search fields are placed with `AND` condition.

Here, if user enters some value for `area` I need to check the area value exists in any one of the tables (`one` or `two`) without breaking the `AND` condition. Tried the below code but it is breaking `AND` rule and considering `OR`. Any suggestions to fix?

```
$result =  Master::where(function ($query) use ($request) {
    if ($request->filter == true) {
        $query->where('user_id', Auth::user()->id);
    }
    // other conditions here
    if (!empty($request->area_from) && !empty($request->area_to)) {
        $query->whereHas('one', function ($query) use ($request) {
            $query->whereBetween('area', [$request->area_from, $request->area_to]);
        });
        $query->orWhereHas('two', function ($query) use ($request) {
            $query->whereBetween('area', [$request->area_from, $request->area_to]);
        });
    }
    // other conditions here

})->with(['one', 'two'])->paginate($request->item);
```

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean with breaking the `AND`.

Comment: @IGP All the search fields should be separated with `AND`. But here because of the `orWhereHas`, the condition is taking everything from that filed without considering previous conditions.

Comment: OH! Just put another where closure encapsulating both whereHas

Answer (score 1):

You are wrapping all of your where statements in brackets. I think what you want to do is pull your first part of the query out of the where clause so that you can easily wrap the `whereHas` part in brackets.

```
// Initialise the model
$query = new Master;

// Start building the query
if ($request->filter == true) {
    $query->where('user_id', Auth::user()->id);
}

if (!empty($request->area_from) && !empty($request->area_to)) {
    // Wrap these in brackets so we don't interfare with the previous where
    $query->where(function($query2) use ($request) {
        $query2->whereHas('one', function ($query3) use ($request) {
            $query3->whereBetween('area', [$request->area_from, $request->area_to]);
        });
        $query2->orWhereHas('two', function ($query3) use ($request) {
            $query3->whereBetween('area', [$request->area_from, $request->area_to]);
        });
    }
}

$query->with(['one', 'two'])->paginate($request->item);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a merged relationship [refer this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24184069/laravel-merge-relationships)

```
public function mergedOneAndTwo($value)
{
    // There two calls return collections
    // as defined in relations.
    $onedata= $this->one;
    $twodata= $this->two;

    // Merge collections and return single collection.
    return $onedata->merge($twodata);
}
```

and use `whereHas('mergedOneAndTwo')`

Answer (score 0):

Using a closer where and making the conditional inside may work fine

```
$master = Master::with('one')->with('two');
$result = $master->where(function($subQuery)
{   
    $subQuery->whereHas('one', function ( $query ) {
        $query->whereBetween('area', [$request->area_from, $request->area_to] ); //assuming  $request->area_from, $request->area_to is range of value
    })
    ->orWhereHas('two', function ( $query ) {
        $query->whereBetween('area', [$request->area_from, $request->area_to] );
    });
});
```