# How to get user information in orm relationship?

Tags: php, laravel, orm

My User.php Model function is this

```
 public function send_connection_requests()
 {
   return $this->hasMany('App\Models\ConnectionRequest','from_user');
 }
 public function received_connection_requests()
 {
   return $this->hasMany('App\Models\ConnectionRequest','to_user');
 }
```

and  my coonectionRequest realtionship is this->

```
public function send_connection_requests()
{
   return $this->belongsto('App\User','id');
}`
 public function received_connection_requests()
 {
   return $this->belongsto('App\User','id');
 }`
```

`

When I am calling function

```
@foreach (Auth::user()->send_connection_requests as $request)

   {{request->to_user}}

@endforech
```

I'm only getting connection request table data which contains from_user and to_user id and i need to show their name which user send request and which user recived request ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

coonectionRequest realtionship is [belongsTo](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/database-testing#belongs-to-relationships), the second parameter is the foreign key column name,

while the third column is the primary column name in the users table:

```
public function send_connection_requests()
{
   return $this->belongsto('App\User','from_user','id');
}
 public function received_connection_requests()
 {
   return $this->belongsto('App\User','to_user','id');
 }
```

Comment: one more doubt if  i want to get both users name from_userid and to_userid ?

Comment: this question is exactly what you want: https://stackoverflow.com/q/24184069/10573560